# Jquery check if all input text, radio, select box are filled

Tags: jquery, html, yii2

I have a form having two section. 
First section having text field, radio button, select box.
Second section have only text fields.
I have disabled the second section when page loads. I am only showing first section when page loads. 
I want to show second section only when i have all fields filled in first section. For this i used jquery code but this is not working for radio type and select box :

```
$('.profile-user-personal-form input[type="text"], .profile-user-personal-form input[type="radio"], .profile-user-personal-form select, .profile-user-personal-form input[type="password"]').bind('keyup',function(){

        // get elements that are empty.
        var empty = $('.profile-user-personal-form input[type="text"], .profile-user-personal-form input[type="password"], .profile-user-personal-form input[type="radio"], .profile-user-personal-form select').map(function(index, el) {
            return !$(el).val() ? el : null;

        }).get();

        // could also be placed outside of the function
        var number = $('.user-leaving-info');


        // check if there are any empty elements, if there are none, show numbers, else hide number.
        !empty.length ? number.css({'opacity': 1, 'pointer-events':'auto'}) : number.css({
                'opacity': 0.2,
                'pointer-events' : 'none',
        });
        !empty.length ? $('html , body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".user-leaving-info").offset().top
        }, 1000) : "";

    });
```

My HTML code look like this :

```
<div class="profile-user-personal-form">
    <div class="form-group mr-30">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <div class="form_control field-user-first_name required">
            <input type="text" id="user-first_name" class="form-control first_name" name="User[first_name]" value="">
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <div class="form_control field-user-last_name required">
            <input type="text" id="user-last_name" class="form-control last_name" name="User[last_name]" value="">
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div class="form-group full-width">
        <h6>I am a : </h6>
        <div class="radio-inline field-user-gender required">

            <input type="hidden" name="User[gender]" value="">
                <div id="user-gender">
                    <label class="radio-inline ">
                        <input type="radio" class="genderName" name="User[gender]" value="Male">male
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline ">
                        <input type="radio" class="genderName" name="User[gender]" value="Female">female
                    </label>
                </div>
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div class="form-group full-width">
        <h6>Birthday</h6>
        <div class="select-box-styling">
            <div class="form-group field-user-month">
                <select id="user-month" class="form-control month" name="User[month]">
                    <option value="1">Jan</option>
                    <option value="2">Feb</option>
                    <option value="3">Mar</option>
                    <option value="4">Apr</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">Jun</option>
                    <option value="7">Jul</option>
                    <option value="8">Aug</option>
                    <option value="9">Sep</option>
                    <option value="10">oct</option>
                    <option value="11">Nov</option>
                    <option value="12">Dec</option>
                </select>
            </div>              
            <div class="form-group field-user-day">

                <select id="user-day" class="form-control day" name="User[day]">

                    <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option>
                </select>

            </div>               
            <div class="form-group field-user-year">

                <select id="user-year" class="form-control year" name="User[year]">
                    <option value="1998">1998</option>
                    <option value="1997">1997</option>
                </select>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please tell me the issue in code ?

Comment: It is better if you could post your relevant HTML code too.

Comment: I have update the html code too

Answer (score 0):

You have made two errors: 1. Radio inputs and select boxes won't respond to `'keyup'` event when changed. You need `'change'` event for them. 2. When calling `val()` on radio, it would always return a value, but it doesn't tell you if it's checked or not, for that use jQuery's `is(':checked')`. Replace your code with this code and it should work:

```
function checkFormFunction(){
    // get elements that are empty.
    var empty = $('.profile-user-personal-form input[type="text"], .profile-user-personal-form input[type="password"], .profile-user-personal-form select').map(function(index, el) {
        return !$(el).val() ? el : null; 
    }).get();

    //check if at least one radio is checked
    var isChecked = $('.profile-user-personal-form input[type="radio"]').is(":checked");

    // could also be placed outside of the function
    var number = $('.user-leaving-info');

    // check if there are any empty elements, a checked radio, if there are none, show numbers, else hide number.
    isChecked && !empty.length ? number.css({'opacity': 1, 'pointer-events':'auto'}) : number.css({
        'opacity': 0.2,
        'pointer-events' : 'none',
    });
    isChecked && !empty.length ? $('html , body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".user-leaving-info").offset().top
    }, 1000) : "";
}

$('.profile-user-personal-form input[type="text"], .profile-user-personal-form input[type="password"]').bind('keyup', checkFormFunction);
$('.profile-user-personal-form input[type="radio"], .profile-user-personal-form select').bind('change', checkFormFunction);
```